# Do repulsor lift vehicles exert a reaction force on the ground below them?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, technology

Let's say I am lying on the ground when my friend runs over me on his speeder bike, does it feel like I've just been run over by a bike or as though a light breeze just passed over me? There doesn't seem to be much visible disturbance in the film, however, it's possible that's just a budget reason or that the compression of the ground simply isn't very visible.

Alternatively does this vary depending on <s>what that writer wants</s> different models of repulsor lifts, the specifics of the planet their on, the altitude the repulsor lift is functioning at etc. etc.

Legends answers are perfectly acceptable if nothing is found in canon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The technology used in repulsorlift vehicles is described as pushing against gravity to maintain altitude. Thus, all you would feel if one repulsorlift vehicle would pass over you would be the breeze created by it's speed.

It's been described that way in the novelizations, technical manuals, RPG materials, etc...

Star Wars D6 game Manual 2.5 by West End Games, page 242:

> By producing antigravity repulsor fields, these drives allow exacting control and high speeds or incredible cargo hauling capacity. [...] Repulsorlift vehicles are also popular because they are not restricted to roads and other smooth pathways — a boon to frontier and poor planets that can't afford funding for highway construction. Almost all atmospheric vehicles, and a majority of "ground" vehicles in the Known Galaxy, rely upon repulsor technology; primitive wheeled, hover and hydrocarbon burning engines are normally found only on the most primitive worlds, or on planets where repulsorlift isn't feasible due to random gravity and radiation fluctuations.

Answer (score 5):

## No (specifically, Trade Federation technology)

Qui-Gon and Jar Jar were fine after being run over by a massive Trade Federation vehicle in *The Phantom Menace*:

The vehicle did not even disturb the vegetation underneath it, other than to create a slight breeze by its passage.

Comment: This only happened because Jar-Jar is a powerful Sith Lord, and he kept them safe by creating Force bubble :P